# Blazor - dynamically change role

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity, blazor

I have a blazor application, in a page I use the following code to display some sections depending of the current user role.

```
        <AuthorizeView Roles="EditorAdmin">
            <Authorized>
                <MatIconButton Icon="dashboard" OnClick="@OnClickDashboard"></MatIconButton>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
```

On the server, I assign a new role with:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync
```

But, it has no impact on the UI, I need to logout and then login.
I wish to update my UI, but how ?

Comment: Perhaps you should use [Reference Tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html).

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I'm facibg the same issue.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: What is your configuration? WASM or Server? If WASM, are you using IdentityServer4?

Comment: You have to implement your AuthenticationStateProvider and call NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged