# Server-side Blazor 5.0 cascading AuthState not updating

Tags: c#, blazor, identity, roles

I have an issue regarding role management in Blazor 5.0.

I want to add or remove role when the user is already authenticated. In my page I use often the

```cs
[CascadingParameter]
protected Task<AuthenticationState> AuthState { get; set; }
```

To check if the user has the correct role.

At one point I use this method to update the role, and an unexpected behaviour happens :

```cs
    protected async Task Cancel()
    {
        var User = await UM.GetUserAsync((await AuthState).User);
        Console.WriteLine("---Before---");
        var BoolAuth1 = (await AuthState).User.IsInRole(Utilisateur.Role_Abonne);
        Console.WriteLine($"AuthState status for role : {BoolAuth1}");
        var Bool1 =await  UM.IsInRoleAsync(User, Utilisateur.Role_Abonne);
        Console.WriteLine($"UserManager status for role : {Bool1}");
        await UM.RemoveFromRoleAsync(User, Utilisateur.Role_Abonne);
        Console.WriteLine("---After----");
        var BoolAuth2 = (await AuthState).User.IsInRole(Utilisateur.Role_Abonne);
        Console.WriteLine($"AuthState status for role : {BoolAuth2}");
        var Bool2 = await UM.IsInRoleAsync(User, Utilisateur.Role_Abonne);
        Console.WriteLine($"UserManager status for role : {Bool2}");
   }
```

And the result is :

```
---Before---
AuthState status for role : True
UserManager status for role : True
---After----
AuthState status for role : True
UserManager status for role : False
```

Change was made in the database, but the AuthState is not refreshed, even reloading the page doesn't solve the problem. I have to LogOut, then Log back in to refresh the AuthState. Which is unfortunate as I use in a lot of different page the current AuthState and things like

```cs
    <AuthorizeView Roles="@Utilisateur.Role_Abonne">
        <Authorized>
            <button class="LogButton" @onclick="Cancel">
                <h5 class="LogButtonText">
                    Disconnect
                </h5>
            </button>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <button class="LogButton">
                <h5 class="LogButtonText" @onclick="Register">
                    Connect
                </h5>
            </button>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

How can I refresh the AuthState without forcing the user to logout ?

[this user has the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592160/blazor-dynamically-change-role) but not response was given.

My current hack, which work until user reload the page is

```cs
protected Task<AuthenticationState> NewTask;
public void RaiseAuthStateChanged(ClaimsPrincipal Claim)
{
    NewTask = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(Claim));
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(NewTask);
}
public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    if (NewTask != null) return NewTask;
    else return base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
}
```

But I find this ugly and I don't even know if this raises security issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the user needing to log out and log back in to see updated roles etc is a known issue/limitation.

I certainly recall hearing the issue discussed in Podcasts etc.